# Is anyone working on a mobile wallet that can facilitate custom coin transactions?

Tags: wallets, tokens, mobile-wallet

I've met some people who are in need of a coin for their collective hackerspace. If I can get my custom coin into a decent mobile wallet (doesn't really need to be super robust) they can start using it for all their internal transactions.

It seems like it would be ideal, if a mobile wallet could import an address (or human readable registration name) of a coin contract. Then the user can click the coin they want to trade and make transactions.

Is anyone working on something like this?

Comment: Looks like you need not only a wallet but also a coin set up for the team, sounds interesting. Have you find anyone yet?

Comment: @NikhilM not yet. I guess I need a wallet-app that supports the coin (i think the Ethereum wallet does but its desktop), and the users will have to send each other a few cents worth of Ether in order to spend on transacting the coin. A bit more complex than I'd like but oh well. You need Ether to do anything I guess.

Comment: Bump, interested in this as well!

Answer (score 1):

We implemented a contract that holds custom tokens, with client side wallet, which signs transactions and passes them to server side wallet, which pushes in ethereum transaction. 
Check out the contract https://github.com/cryptofiat/contract and the whole project https://github.com/cryptofiat/
Feel